# unable to remove variables from a dataset

Tags: r

when I run the following command

```
select(Auto_imports, -c( make, num_of_cylinders,engine_type, fuel_system))
```

and verify that the variables are gone. They are still there.

> Auto_imports[1:10,]

```
   symboling normalized_losses        make fuel_type aspiration num_doors  body_style drive_wheels engine_location wheel_base length width height curb_weight
1          3                NA alfa-romero       gas        std       two convertible          rwd           front       88.6  168.8  64.1   48.8        2548
2          3                NA alfa-romero       gas        std       two convertible          rwd           front       88.6  168.8  64.1   48.8        2548
3          1                NA alfa-romero       gas        std       two   hatchback          rwd           front       94.5  171.2  65.5   52.4        2823
4          2               164        audi       gas        std      four       sedan          fwd           front       99.8  176.6  66.2   54.3        2337
5          2               164        audi       gas        std      four       sedan          4wd           front       99.4  176.6  66.4   54.3        2824
6          2                NA        audi       gas        std       two       sedan          fwd           front       99.8  177.3  66.3   53.1        2507
7          1               158        audi       gas        std      four       sedan          fwd           front      105.8  192.7  71.4   55.7        2844
8          1                NA        audi       gas        std      four       wagon          fwd           front      105.8  192.7  71.4   55.7        2954
9          1               158        audi       gas      turbo      four       sedan          fwd           front      105.8  192.7  71.4   55.9        3086
10         0                NA        audi       gas      turbo       two   hatchback          4wd           front       99.5  178.2  67.9   52.0        3053
   engine_type num_of_cylinders engine_size fuel_system bore stroke compression_ratio horsepower peak_rpm city_mpg highway_mpg Price
1         dohc             four         130        mpfi 3.47   2.68               9.0        111     5000       21          27 13495
2         dohc             four         130        mpfi 3.47   2.68               9.0        111     5000       21          27 16500
3         ohcv              six         152        mpfi 2.68   3.47               9.0        154     5000       19          26 16500
4          ohc             four         109        mpfi 3.19   3.40              10.0        102     5500       24          30 13950
5          ohc             five         136        mpfi 3.19   3.40               8.0        115     5500       18          22 17450
6          ohc             five         136        mpfi 3.19   3.40               8.5        110     5500       19          25 15250
7          ohc             five         136        mpfi 3.19   3.40               8.5        110     5500       19          25 17710
8          ohc             five         136        mpfi 3.19   3.40               8.5        110     5500       19          25 18920
9          ohc             five         131        mpfi 3.13   3.40               8.3        140     5500       17          20 23875
10         ohc             five         131        mpfi 3.13   3.40               7.0        160     5500       16          22 23870
```

Comment: Check your syntax. `select(Auto_imports, c( -make, -num_of_cylinders, -engine_type, -fuel_system))`.

Comment: @Limey, this shouldn't be the issue. Your suggestions and the code from the TO are equivalent and should lead to the same result.

Comment: @deschen: You are correct. My apologies.  But in which case I cannot reproduce the OP's problem: both `select(mtcars, -c(wt, mpg))` and `select(mtcars, c(-wt, -mpg))` work as expected for me.

Comment: `select` doesn't change the data.frame, it returns a new data.frame. Be sure to save the result somewhere by assigning it to a variable if you want to use it later.

Comment: Objects in R are generally immutable. When you called the function, the return value was a mutated copy of the dataframe. Since you didn't assign the return value to a new object using <-, the return value just printed to the console. It was a *pure* function, because it didn't mutate any objects; it just returned a value, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Have you assigned this select statement to the `Auto_imports` object?

Try this if you are still using dplyr:

`Auto_imports <- select(Auto_imports, -c( make,num_of_cylinders,engine_type, fuel_system))`

or even using R base:

`Auto_imports <- Auto_imports[,!(names(Auto_imports) %in% c("make", "num_of_cylinders","engine_type", "fuel_system"))]`